# how can I set custom attribute value for entity (for product) in MFTF test

Tags: magento2, mftf

The selected customer attribute is not saving for created by MFTF product (**https://prnt.sc/tqqy8m**).

Let me know please.

Comment: or how to use <requiredEntity type="custom_attribute"> ?

Comment: Have found another solution. Like login to Admin Panel and fill this custom attribute manually, but anyway maybe there is still exists a way how to this using <requiredEntity type="custom_attribute">
?????